# Extending DbFunctions in Entity Framework Core?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

With .NET Core 3.1.1 and Entity Framework Core 3.1.1, I have:

```cs
var query = from user in context.Users
            join userRole in userRoleView on user.Id equals userRole.UserId into gj
            from p in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new
                   {
                        user.Id,
                        user.UserName,
                        RoleName = p.Rolename,
                        user.CreatedUtc,
                        user.ModifiedUtc,
                  };

if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(conditions.Keyword))
{
    query = query.Where(d => EF.Functions.Like(d.UserName, "%" + conditions.Keyword + "%"));
}
```

This is working well, and then I would like to have `EF.Functions.Contains(d.UserName, conditions.Keyword)`, so I wrote an extension:

```cs
public static class DbFunctionsExtensions
{
    public static bool Contains(this DbFunctions _, string matchExpression, string keyword)
    {
        return _.Like(matchExpression, "%" + keyword + "%");
    }
}
```

However, when running

```
query.Where(d => EF.Functions.Contains(d.UserName, conditions.Keyword))
```

I get this exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException
>   ... could not be translated.
>
> Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either `AsEnumerable()`, `AsAsyncEnumerable()`, `ToList()`, or `ToListAsync()`. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.
>
> Source=Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore
>
> StackTrace:
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.g__CheckTranslated|8_0(ShapedQueryExpression translated, <>c__DisplayClass8_0& )
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
>   at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
>   at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
>   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
>      at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
>      at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.RelationalQueryableMethodTranslatingExpressionVisitor.VisitMethodCall(MethodCallExpression methodCallExpression)
>      at System.Linq.Expressions.MethodCallExpression.Accept(ExpressionVisitor visitor)
>      at System.Linq.Expressions.ExpressionVisitor.Visit(Expression node)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.QueryCompilationContext.CreateQueryExecutor[TResult](Expression query)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Storage.Database.CompileQuery[TResult](Expression query, Boolean async)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.CompileQueryCore[TResult](IDatabase database, Expression query, IModel model, Boolean async)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.<>c__DisplayClass9_0`1.<Execute>b__0()
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQueryCore[TFunc](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.CompiledQueryCache.GetOrAddQuery[TResult](Object cacheKey, Func`1 compiler)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.QueryCompiler.Execute[TResult](Expression query)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryProvider.Execute[TResult](Expression expression)
>      at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.EntityQueryable`1.GetEnumerator()
>      at System.Collections.Generic.LargeArrayBuilder`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 items)
>      at System.Collections.Generic.EnumerableHelpers.ToArray[T](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at System.Linq.Enumerable.ToArray[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)
>      at APS.WebPos.DAL.SearchOperations.GetActivePeopleByKeyword(String keyword) in C:\VSProjects\ApsCloudTrunk\APS.WebPos.DALCore\SearchOperations.cs:line 96
>      at APS.WebPos.WebApi.Controllers.SearchController.GetActivePeopleByKeyword(String keyword) in C:\VSProjects\ApsCloudTrunk\APS.WebPos.WebApiCore\Controllers\SearchController.cs:line 25
>      at Microsoft.Extensions.Internal.ObjectMethodExecutor.Execute(Object target, Object[] parameters)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ActionMethodExecutor.SyncObjectResultExecutor.Execute(IActionResultTypeMapper mapper, ObjectMethodExecutor executor, Object controller, Object[] arguments)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
>      at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()

Is it possible to extend DbFunctions in application with Entity Framework Core, and use it in LINQ? How?

Remarks:

`String.Contains()` is case sensitive in EF Core query, though it is case insensitive in EF being translated into LIKE in SQL.

Comment: Can you show how you're calling `Contains`?

Comment: here it is: `query.Where(d => EF.Functions.Contains(d.UserName, conditions.Keyword))`

Comment: I'm curious if you're usage is conflicting with the [existing Contains extension method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.sqlserverdbfunctionsextensions.contains?view=efcore-3.1#Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_SqlServerDbFunctionsExtensions_Contains_Microsoft_EntityFrameworkCore_DbFunctions_System_String_System_String_). If so, you may need to call your extension method explicitly (e.g. `DbFunctionsExtensions.Contains(EF.Functions, d.UserName, conditions.Keyword)`)

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple one -> context.Users.Where(x => (conditions.Keyword == null || x.UserName.Contains(conditions.Keyword))). If conditions.Keyword is null, it skips filter.

```
var query = from user in context.Users.Where(x => (conditions.Keyword == null || x.UserName.Contains(conditions.Keyword)))
                        join userRole in userRoleView
                        on user.Id equals userRole.UserId into gj
                        from p in gj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                        select new
                        {
                            user.Id,
                            user.UserName,
                            RoleName = p.Rolename,
                            user.CreatedUtc,
                            user.ModifiedUtc,
                        };
```

Comment: This is not working well in EntityFrameworkCore, since String.Contains() is case sensitive, though in EF, it is case insensitive.

Comment: then how about using ToLower()?  x.UserName.ToLower().Contains(conditions.Keyword.ToLower())

Comment: In EF, String.Contains() is translated into LIKE of SQL, however, in EF Core, obviously this is not the case. I want the same translation into LIKE. In other words, do the case-insensitive in SQL, not in app codes.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter of the `Where` method is an `Expression` and its body is irrelevant when the query is being translated into SQL. That is why you are getting an exception.

To make it work you need to construct an Expression dynamically.

```cs
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Like<T>(Expression<Func<T, string>> prop, string keyword)
{
    var concatMethod = typeof(string).GetMethod(nameof(string.Concat), new[] { typeof(string), typeof(string) });
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(
        Expression.Call(
            typeof(DbFunctionsExtensions),
            nameof(DbFunctionsExtensions.Like),
            null,
            Expression.Constant(EF.Functions),
            prop.Body,
            Expression.Add(
                Expression.Add(
                    Expression.Constant("%"),
                    Expression.Constant(keyword),
                    concatMethod),
                Expression.Constant("%"),
                concatMethod)),
        prop.Parameters);
}
```

And then use it in your query

```cs
if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(conditions.Keyword))
{
    query = query.Where(Like<User>(d => d.UserName, conditions.Keyword));
}
```

P.S. The way the question is titled looks close to what [Scalar function mapping](http://anthonygiretti.com/2018/01/11/entity-framework-core-2-scalar-function-mapping/) is, but its not applicable in the case of LIKE clause.

Comment: I am not asking how to implement LIKE in EF Core, since LIKE is already built in as an extension. What I am asking is how to implement Contains as a language shortcut to LIKE, so I don't have to add the percentage sign everywhere in codes.

Comment: And thats what I have created for you. Did you saw the second code block?

Comment: I do see, however, since LIKE is built-in, I don't want to change its behavior and somewhere in the application I still need LIKE which is more flexible than Contains though more verbose. Contains is a subset of LIKE and I would want EF Core to translate Contains in LINQ into LIKE.